# A question related to discrete and subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

I am unable to think how to prove this question.

> Question is - Let A be a subgroup of Real Line under Addition. Show that either A is dense in Real Line Or else the subspace topology of A is discrete topology.

I tried by assuming A is not dense in Real Line but I am unable to prove that A intersection is discrete topology.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Prove that $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if $\inf\{|x-y|\colon x,y\in A\}=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Either $A$ has a least positive element or it doesn't. The former gives you a discrete set and the latter a dense set (provided $A \neq \{0\}$).

---

**EDIT:** Adding details for the case where $A$ has a least positive element.
Let $\epsilon \in A$ be this least positive element.

**Claim.** $|x - y| > \epsilon/2$ for all $x, y \in A$ with $x\neq y$.
*Proof.* Suppose not. Let $x, y \in A$ be distinct such that $|x - y| \le \epsilon/2$.
Set $d = x - y$. Note that $d \in A$ and $-d \in A$. Thus, we may assume that $d > 0$.

Thus, we have $0 < d \le \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$. This contradicts that $\epsilon$ is the smallest positive element of $A$.

Thus, the claim is proven and it follows that $A$ is discrete.

Comment: can you 
 please elaborate?

Comment: Which of the two cases give you trouble?

Comment: the case in which A has a least element.  Can you please tell?

Comment: Have added details